# SSL error by creating session in watson studio with assistant service

Tags: python, ssl

I use the Lite-Version of the IBM cloud and tried to connect my assistant service to the jupyter notebook in watson studio. When I try to create a session, an error occured because the ssl certificate seems to be invalid. What I have done before:

```
project = Project(project_id='my_id', project_access_token='my_token')

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('my_auth')
sdk_object = AssistantV1(version='2020-04-01', authenticator=authenticator)
sdk_object.set_service_url('https://api.eu- de.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/my_inst/v2/assistants/')

assistant_information = {'workspace_id' : '',
                    'skill_id' : 'my_skill',
                     'assistant_id' : 'my_assi'}
```

And then I tried to create the session:

```
 session_id = sdk_object.create_session(assistant_id = 'my_id').get_result()['session_id']
```

Executing the last line failed:

> ApiException Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> 1 session_id = sdk_object.create_session(
> ----> 2  assistant_id = 'my_id'
> 3 ).get_result()['session_id'] /opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_watson/assistant_v2.py
> in create_session(self, assistant_id, **kwargs)
> 122                                        params=params)
> 123
> --> 124         response = self.send(request)
> 125         return response
> 126  /opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py
> in send(self, request, **kwargs)
> 300                                         status_code=response.status_code)
> 301
> --> 302             raise ApiException(response.status_code, http_response=response)
> 303         except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> 304             logging.exception(self.ERROR_MSG_DISABLE_SSL) ApiException: Error: Resource not found, Code: 404 ,
> X-global-transaction-id: 8f06c508-d0f6-436f-8719-d1cb99257954

I also tried it with assistant_v1 and got the same error with ssl certificate.
What can I do to get a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

this URL won´t work:
sdk_object.set_service_url('https://api.eu- de.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/my_inst/v2/assistants/')

delete the part 'vs/assistants/' and you will create your session without worry about SSL.